# ListView, setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android-listview

thanks in advance to anyone who views and helps out with my problem. I have a simple app that displays html pages in a webview. I generate a list from a string-array in the strings.xml. Each item shows up in the ListView in the order they are listed in the array with no problem. The setOnItemClickListener and loadUrl work just fine until you to scroll and select. Once scrolling and then selecting, the wrong html file is loaded (one different than selected) sometimes it will not load anything and will crash or revert to the main loading activity. I have tested this on numerous size and style emulators and on a nexus 7 tablet.

here is the class that displays the list and loads the selected html file into a WebView:

```
    public class MKI extends Activity 
    {
   ListView listView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_style);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.maintkits_array);
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));  

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p,long id) 
        {
              ListView lv = (ListView) parent;
              TextView tv = (TextView) lv.getChildAt(p);
              String s = tv.getText().toString();
              setContentView(R.layout.html_view); 
              WebView mbrowser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.viewHTML); 
              mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ki/"+ s +".html");

        }
    });
}
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to separate this into two activities.  One that handles the URL selection display, and one that handles displaying the web page.

Something like:

```
public class MKI extends Activity {

   private ListView listView;
   private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_style);

    String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.maintkits_array);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list); 

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);  
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int p,long id) 
        {
              String url = adapter.getItem(p);
              Intent viewPage = new Intent(MKI.this, WebActivity.class);
              viewPage.putExtra(EXTRA_URL, url);
              startActivity(viewPage);
        }
    });
}
  }
```

---

```
public class WebActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_URL = "EXTRA_URL";

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         

        if(!getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_URL)){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must provide url to" this.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else {
                     setContentView(R.layout.store_activity);
             webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

                     String url = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
                     mbrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ki/"+ url +".html");
                }



         .....


        }
```

Comment: thanks my good man. this seems to work well. I have only tried its functionality a little but it seems to work perfectly. Once again. thanks.